# Ubuntu wifi problems with new router

Tags: networking, wireless, router

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have recently installed a new TP-LINK TL-WR841N Wireless N router at my home. Since then websites such as Facebook, Yahoo, Stackoverflow itself are not properly opening. The browser is not able to access the images, CSS/JS files for these websites. It is same for all Firefox, Chrome, Chromium Browser. The developer console gives **CORS**(Cross-origin resource sharing) errors when accessing these websites over wifi. Instead when i use my mobile phone as hot-spot and access these sites using my mobile data everything is working as it should. Also there is no problem in accessing wifi through this router when using Windows 7 or 8.

I have already tried the following to no good effect :

- Restarting the system
- Restarting the Router
- Restarting Network Adapter
- Updating the system

Answer (score 1):

After searching on a lot of sites and blogs, apparently using an open DNS such as 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 rather than using automatic DNS solved the problem. I still don't know why the automatic DNS for the router is not working for Ubuntu although it is working fine for Windows.